# Bundle ID replacing digits with '-'

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I am creating a project named '99miles'.
Upon doing so, the bundle ID that was expected to end with '.99miles' is now '.-9miles'. 
This happens with project names starting with digits(0-9) and some special characters.

First character with digits and all special characters are replaced with '-'.

I want the bundle id to end with '.99miles'

1. Why is this happening.
2. Should I go for force replacing of _9miles with 99miles after creating project?

[image]

Comment: Down voters do add you comments.

Comment: You can choose your own bundle identifier as long as it is available

Comment: Thanks @AkshanshThakur. Yes I can force change the bundle ID, but that makes this kind of conversion pointless. I suppose there must be a reason for this and force change might break things.

Comment: See, if you understand bundle ID, you'd know that they are just used for creating provision profiles or integrating with SDK's (for e.g. Facebook). So, don't worry about it. A suggested bundle id though, is of form : com.yourusername.appname or com.yourusername.appname.ios
something like that is widely accepted

Comment: AFAIK bundle ID has nothing to do with 'integrating with SDK's'. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: Well, this doc tells that Bundle ID's have to be unique to your app. I think that is a common knowledge. What I was saying is that from my career in ios Development, I have used bundle ID at only two places, while adding SDK's to my app or to create provision profile. It hasnt 'affected' my app in any way. and reverse domain is what I told you eg. "com.whatever.whatever" 
Check this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation
This is what happens, your bundle id is concatenation of product name and organization id.

Comment: In your case bundle id wasnt exactly what you wanted, so I suggested custom reverse domain name. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112660/discussion-between-dinesh-hudinwal-and-akshansh-thakur).

Comment: Have you solved you problem? I have the same...can't use digits..